# Error #1009 with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

I'm a rather new to programming with AS3 and started with the rather old MJW AvoiderGame tutorial. Since this tutorial is a bit old, I have got a lot of errors while trying to learn AS3. Now I got an error that I cant figure out.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at AvoiderGame/onTick()
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

The problem seems to be in the onTick function in AvoiderGame class. Here is the AvoiderGame class:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

public class AvoiderGame extends MovieClip 
{
    public var army:Array;
    public var enemy:Enemy;
    public var avatar:Avatar;
    public var gameTimer:Timer;
    public var gameClock:Clock;

    public function AvoiderGame() 
    {
        army = new Array();
        var newEnemy = new Enemy( 200, -15 );
        army.push( newEnemy );
        addChild( newEnemy );

        avatar = new Avatar();
        addChild( avatar );
        avatar.x = mouseX;
        avatar.y = mouseY;

        gameTimer = new Timer( 25 );
        gameTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick );
        gameTimer.start();
    }

    public function onTick( timerEvent:TimerEvent ):void 
    {
        gameClock.addToValue( 25 );
        if ( Math.random() < 0.1 )
        {
            var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 800;
            var newEnemy:Enemy = new Enemy( randomX, -15 );
            army.push( newEnemy );
            addChild( newEnemy );
            gameScore.addToValue( 10 );
        }
        avatar.x = mouseX;
        avatar.y = mouseY;

        for each ( var enemy:Enemy in army ) 
        {
            enemy.moveDownABit();
            if ( avatar.hitTestObject( enemy ) ) 
            {
                gameTimer.stop();
                dispatchEvent( new AvatarEvent( AvatarEvent.DEAD ) );
            }
        }
    }

    public function getFinalScore():Number
    {
        return gameScore.currentValue;
    }

    public function getFinalClockTime():Number
    {
        return gameClock.currentValue;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `public var gameClock:Clock;` where do you instantiate this?

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly obvious - in `onTick()` the first line is

```
gameClock.addToValue( 25 );
```

but you never initialize the `gameClock` field. That way it has the default `null` value hence the error you see. You should initialize it accordingly just the way you initialize the `gameTimer` field.